# Wait for element to change in playwright with TypeScript

Tags: playwright

Hello I have an issue with tables
I have a table with column and rows, I need to verify a value inside a cell before and after an action.

```
let beforeActionText = await commonPage.SearchResultsFirstRow.textContent();
```

perform update operation on the same cell.

```
let afterActionText = await commonPage.SearchResultsFirstRow.textContent();

await expect.soft(afterActionText).toBe(Riskname);
```

The problem is as the element exist anyway, the script give me randomly beforeActionText or afterActionText, so it generate flakiness

have tried page.waitforloadstate() and used some pooling period as well.

But i am expecting some generic way to solve

Comment: What is the entire snippet of code of test including the code line where you are updating the cell text?

Comment: You might get better answers if you share the proper context with all relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

[toHaveText](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-text)  retries by [itself](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#auto-retrying-assertions), you don't need to wrap it again in another expect statement.

This will do the same thing:

```
await expect(locator).toHaveText('valueAfterUpdate')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Playwright [expect .toPass assertion](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#expecttopass):

```
await expect(async () => {
    await expect(commonPage.SearchResultsFirstRow.textContent()).toHaveText(Riskname);
}).toPass();
```

This answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74901847/playwright-equivalent-to-protractors-browser-wait-to-loop-while-condition-is-no/74902100#74902100)